# Removing content from start and end of string (PHP)

Tags: php, strip, str-replace

I'm trying to get a users ID from a string such as:

http://www.abcxyz.com/123456789/

To appear as 123456789 essentially stripping the info up to the first / and also removing the end /. I did have a look around on the net but there seems to be so many solutions but nothing answering both start and end.

Thanks :)

**Update 1**

The link can take two forms: mod_rewrite as above and also "http://www.abcxyz.com/profile?user_id=123456789"

Comment: Can the URL contain more, e.g. `http://example.com/12345/foo` and if so: will the number be always the first? And how long can that number be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`parse_url()`](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to cleanly extract the path component from the URL:

```
$path = parse_URL("http://www.example.com/123456789/", PHP_URL_PATH);
```

and then split the path into its elements using `explode()`:

```
$path = trim($path, "/"); // Remove starting and trailing slashes
$path_exploded = explode("/", $path);
```

and then output the first component of the path:

```
echo $path_exploded[0]; // Will output 123456789
```

this method will work in edge cases like

- `http://www.example.com/123456789?test`
- `http://www.example.com//123456789`
- `www.example.com/123456789/abcdef`

and even

- `/123456789/abcdef`

Comment: if there is only the number, you can just trim: `echo trim(parse_url('http://www.abcxyz.com/123456789/', PHP_URL_PATH), '/');`

Comment: Thats great, that works fine. Could I also get this to work in the case of "http://www.abcxyz.com/profile?user_id=123456789"?

Comment: @lethal yes, you can get the `user_id` part by using `PHP_URL_QUERY` in the `parse_url` call. See the manual page for all possible combinations.

Comment: @lethal in case where you are using `PHP_URL_QUERY` you might want to use `parse_str(parse_url('http://www.abcxyz.com/profile?user_id=123456789', PHP_URL_QUERY), $parts);`. That would parse the query string into `$parts` which you could then access with `$parts['user_id']` to get the value.

Comment: Note that using `trim($path, '/')` will remove *all* empty path segments at the begin and end.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'http://www.abcxyz.com/123456789/';
$parts = array_filter(explode('/', $string));
$id = array_pop($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other numbers in the URL, you can also do

```
echo filter_var('http://www.abcxyz.com/123456789/', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

to strip out everything that is not a digit.

That might be somewhat quicker than using the `parse_url`+`parse_str` combination.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID always is the last member of the URL

```
$url="http://www.abcxyz.com/123456789/";
$id=preg_replace(",.*/([0-9]+)/$,","\\1",$url);
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your domain does not contain any numbers, you can handle both situations (with or without user_id) using:

```
<?php

$string1 = 'http://www.abcxyz.com/123456789/';
$string2 = 'http://www.abcxyz.com/profile?user_id=123456789';

preg_match('/[0-9]+/',$string1,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);


preg_match('/[0-9]+/',$string2,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);


?>
```